# Adding an entity from master entity in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to do ORM and add from a parent entity (Batch) to the child entity (Candidate),

I made the relations as below:

Batch Class:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "batch", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Candidate> candidates;
```

Candidate Class:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BatchID")
    private Batch batch;
```

I tried to use JPA Repository from the BatchRepository and from the CandidateRepository

Here I tried to add it via the parent entity, but it didn't work:

```
    public void addCandidateToBatch(int batchId, int candidateId) {
        Batch batch = batchRepository.findById(batchId).get();

        Candidate candidate = candidateRepository.findById(candidateId).get();

        batch.getCandidates().add(candidate);
        batchRepository.save(batch);
    }
```

Alternatively also tried to add it from the child entity, and it actually worked :

```
    public void addBatchToCandidate(int batchId, int candidateId) {
        Candidate candidate = candidateRepository.findById(candidateId).get();
        Batch batch = batchRepository.findById(batchId).get();
        candidate.setBatch(batch);
        candidateRepository.save(candidate);
    }
```

Can someone help enlighten me why did it work on one side, but wont work on the other?
And is there a way to make both of them work?

Comment: can you share your batch and candidate objects?

Comment: You have a bi-directional relationship so you shuld be adding both references. So when adding a Candidate to the Batch you also need to do the opposite. You also told the Batch class that it is managed on the Candidate.batch field, which you don't set in your first (it still is `null`) regardless of the fact that it was added to the collection.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hi, this is the 2nd time you help me solve a problem :D, 
You are right, I need to set it first..
Thank you! Your explanation is as always very clear for me to understand.